linear independence of $n \times n$ matrix
Find all the positive integers n that satisfy the following conditions: there exist two $n \times n$ matrices(over real field) $X$ and $Y$, such that for any non-trivial n-dimensional vector $ \alpha $, $X \cdot \alpha $ and $Y \cdot \alpha$ are linearly independent (i.e., $c X \cdot \alpha \neq Y \cdot \alpha$ for any real number c ).
I first exclude $n=1$. Then as for $n=2$, I find $X$  is the identity matrix while $Y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
but I'm not sure about how to proceed this question.

Just to clarify, are you working with matrices over real field or complex field?

Real field. Sorry for the confusion

I first assumed that you are working over ground field $\mathbb{R}$. If we can find two matrices $X$ and $Y$ such that $\det(cX-Y) \ne 0$ for all real number $c$, we are done - since this implies that for all $\alpha$ such that $$c X\cdot\alpha = Y\cdot\alpha \Leftrightarrow (cX - Y)\cdot\alpha =0,$$ $\alpha$ must be trivial. Now note that $X,Y$ must be both invertible matrices, otherwise there will be non zero vector $\alpha$ such that $X\cdot \alpha$ and $Y\cdot \alpha$ are linearly dependent. Then
$$\det(cX-Y) = \det(cI -YX^{-1})\det(X)$$
So we will want to choose $X,Y$ such that $YX^{-1}$ has no real eigenvalues. Clearly if $n$ is odd, this can't be satisfied, thus we eliminated all odd integers. If $n$ is even, then you can choose $YX^{-1}$ to be the diagonal block matrix
$$YX^{-1} =\begin{pmatrix}
A_{1} \\
& \ddots \\
& & A_{k}
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $n=2k$ and $A_i =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ for all $1 \le i \le k$. This matrix has only eigenvalues $\pm i$, thus implies $\det(cI-YX^{-1})$ has no real roots,  and $cX-Y$ is therefore an invertible matrix for all real number $c$.
